# Multi-line SQL statement formatting in Python using black formatter

Tags: python, sql, formatting

When formatting, **black** ends up concatenating multiline SQL statements:

Before formatting:

```
df = pd.read_sql(
"SELECT TOP 1000 * " \
"FROM [ETZ3BSC1].[NT0001\BD9524].[AA_Trades]", conn
)
```

After formatting:

```
df = pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT TOP 1000 * " "FROM [ETZ3BSC1].[NT0001\BD9524].[AA_Trades]", conn
)
```

Is it possible to enable multi-line SQL statement support? Adding `# fmt: off` and `# fmt: on` before and after the code works but I'm interested in multi-line SQL code support, not disabling the formatter completely.

Answer (score 2):

Python's multiline string syntax should work here:

```
df = pd.read_sql("""
    SELECT TOP 1000 *
    FROM [ETZ3BSC1].[NT0001\BD9524].[AA_Trades]""", conn
)
```

Comment: It does but this ends up highlighting way too much background characters in PyCharm for example (all the way to the end of the screen).